# Bond order of HCO3- as compared to (CO3)2-

Tags: bond

How can we say that the bond order of $\ce{HCO3-}$ is less than that of $\ce{CO3^2-}$? I see that the resonance in $\ce{HCO3-}$ is not as effective as in latter because in latter it is equi-energy resonating structures, and thus energy released in $\ce{HCO3-}$ would be less. But how does that relate to the bond order? The bond order of $\ce{CO3^2-}$ should be $\ce{4/3}$, but why can we say that $\ce{HCO3-}$ will be slightly less than $\ce{4/3}$?

Comment: Can we really?$%$

Comment: See previous post http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/bond-order-for-carbonate-ion-for-resonance

Comment: Yes but then can we talk about BO or Bond length of HCO3-?

Comment: You can view bicarbonate approximately as hydroxyl + carboxylate, with bond orders appropriate for them.